# obtaining foreign key from DEPENDENT possibility in create table SQL

Tags: sql, entity-framework, database-design, entity-relationship

Lets say you have two entity named Parent and Child.
Child entity is DEPENDENT of Parent entity.
A weak key of child entity is the NAMEOFCHILD.
Is it possible for the Parent entity to have NAMEOFCHILD as a foreign key?

This idea has not been talked about in class. I was wondering is this possible in SQL?
If so, should i just add

```
 FOREIGN KEY (NAMEOFCHILD) source CHILD
```

in my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database schema, yes (if `Child.NAMEOFCHILD` has a unique index). In entity framework, no. EF doesn't support associations to unique indexes (yet). But this is just on the technical level. Whether it's *meaningful* is another question.

Also, beware of painting yourself in a corner. When both foreign keys are not nullable you'd never be able to insert data, because you can't insert two records at a time and sequential inserts always cause foreign key violations. You would be able to design the database schema but never get any data in.

Comment: When you mean SQL as in data definition language (DDL), yes.